# Facebook - How to Upload Photo Via URL?

Tags: facebook, upload, photo

For example i have WordPress installed on my website. i want to upload Pictures on Facebook via URL's. MY image Url is:

http://example.com/wp-content/abc123.jpg

Now, i want to upload this image on Facebook via my own website directly into an specific album. I am totally N00b! So don't know anything about coding..

My Aim is to create a cover website.

****SECOND UPDATE*** *:
Here is the code i am using right now:

```
  <?php
      $app_id = "12354";
      $app_secret = "1213243434";
      $post_login_url = "http://example.com/sdsds";
      $album_id = "1234224";
      $photo_url = "http://example.coom/test.jpg";
      $photo_caption = "my caption";

  $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

  //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
  if (!$code){ 
    $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
      . "client_id=" .  $app_id
      . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
      .  "&scope=publish_stream";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url
      . "'</script>");
  } else {
    $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
      . "client_id=" . $app_id
      . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
      . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
      . "&code=" . $code;
    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $access_token = $params['access_token'];

    // POST to Graph API endpoint to upload photos
    $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/" 
      . $album_id . "/photos?"
      . "url=" . urlencode($photo_url)
      . "&message=" . urlencode($photo_caption)
      . "&method=POST"
      . "&access_token=" .$access_token;

    echo '<html><body>';
       echo file_get_contents($graph_url);

    echo '</body></html>';
  }
?>
```

So From this code i am able to upload "test.jpg" to facebook but now the problem is I don't want to upload only one image, i want to upload lot of images so i don't want to change "$photo_url = "http://example.coom/test.jpg";" this code for new photos any help would be appreciate!

Comment: This is more of a help site, not a "we'll just give you the code" site. I suggest you take a look at the http://developers.facebook.com site and specifically https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: On top of that, specifically this post https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/ should have information about uploading via a url

Answer (score 4):

You can't upload a photo from a url, it's not even considered as "uploading" since you don't actually upload the pic, just point to the url.

What you need to do is to get the actual image data and send it yourself to facebook over a POST request to this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos
```

with the params: *message* and *source*.

If you don't have the image locally on the server, then you will need to download it, read its' content and then post it over to facebook.

---

## Edit

Thanks to @TommyBs comment, I see that it is ineed possible to upload via url.
I'll leave the answer since it talks about the alternative.

---

## 2nd Edit

If you want to upload a few images, you have 2 options (as I see it):

(1) Use the [Batch Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) provided by facebook.
You'll have to test if it works with this specific method, I have no idea since I've never tried uploading an image to facebook using a url.

(2) Send a request per image, something like:

```
function uploadPicture($albumId, $photoUrl, $message, $token) {
     $url= "https://graph.facebook.com/" 
        . $albumId . "/photos?"
        . "url=" . urlencode($photoUrl)
        . "&message=" . urlencode($message)
        . "&method=POST"
        . "&access_token=" . $token;

     return file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Then just reuse this function with different parameters.

Comment: yeah it's quite hidden, I only remembered it as I had seen it once. Someone has actually raised a bug on facebook about the fact it isn't in their documentation so hopefully it will get documented eventually!

Comment: okay thanks for the help guys specially @TommyBs for code :) now i am able to upload photo to facebook. but now please i just want to know how to upload so many photos from the same code. here is the code i am using

Comment: <?php
  $app_id = "APP_ID";
  $app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
  $post_login_url = "POST_AUTH_REDIRECT_URL";
  $album_id = "ALBUM_ID";
  $photo_url = "PHOTO_URL";
  $photo_caption = "PHOTO_CAPTION";
?>

Comment: I can't say that I understand what you want.. Please try to explain a bit better. Also, please edit your original question with the added code so that it would be readable.

Comment: i am able to upload "test.jpg" to facebook but now the problem is I don't want to upload only one image, i want to upload lot of images so i don't want to change "$photo_url = "http://example.coom/test.jpg";" this code for new photos any help would be appreciate!

Comment: actually i want to something like this http://www.example.com/?url=mywebsitephotourl.jpg

Comment: There's nothing in that link that has ANYTHING to do with what was discussed in this thread.